# Prevent Event Trigger on Parent From Child - React native - e.stopPropagation() -

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, styled-components

I have a react native app. And I am using react-native-paper for the cards in a list.

And I have text detail on the card that has to act as a button. Because if a user press on the text detail then something has to happen . In this case show the list.accordion.

But the problem I am facing. I can't figure out how to trigger the text detail.

So I have a component with some default content. Because the data is comming from a api call:

```
/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */

import {
    ButtonDetail,
    CategoryCard,
    CategoryGroupCardCover,
    Detail,
} from "./category-info-card.styles";

import { Card } from "react-native-paper";
import { React } from "react";
import { Text } from "../../../components/typography/text.component";


export const CategoryInfoCard = ({ category = {} }) => {
    const {
        name = "Zoogdieren",
        images = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/20/18/03/cat-2083492_960_720.jpg",
        icon = "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSE3_hmm2zWrH4ZLUoqEr4FUb5f-BIn9_c5Qg&usqp=CAU",
        detail = "Detail",
    } = category;

    return (
        <CategoryCard
            elevation={5}
            style={{
                borderTopLeftRadius: 0,
                borderTopRightRadius: 0,
                borderBottomLeftRadius: 0,
                borderBottomRightRadius: 0,
            }}>
            <Text variant="caption" style={{ left: 100 }}>
                {name}
            </Text>
            <CategoryGroupCardCover source={{ uri: images }} />
            <Card.Actions>
                <ButtonDetail>
                    <Detail>{detail}</Detail>
                </ButtonDetail>
            </Card.Actions>         
        </CategoryCard>
    );
};
```

And I am using the library styling.components. So ButtonDetail looks:

```
export const ButtonDetail = styled.TouchableOpacity`
    background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.bg.primary};
    width: 100%;
`;
```

and the component that is loading the data is:

```
export const CategoryScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { loading, error, categoryList } = useContext(CategoryContext);
    const [breakfastExpanded, setBreakfastExpanded] = useState(false);
    //console.log(navigation);
    return (
        <SafeArea>
            {loading && (
                <LoadingContainer>
                    <ActivityIndicator animating={true} color={MD2Colors.green200} />
                </LoadingContainer>
            )}
            <Search />
            <CategoryList
                data={categoryList}
                renderItem={({ item }) => {
                    return (
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("groepen", { subcategories: item.id })}>
                            <Spacer position="top" size="large">
                                <CategoryInfoCard category={item} />
                            </Spacer>

                            <List.Accordion
                                title="Breakfast"
                                left={(props) => <List.Icon {...props} icon="bread-slice" />}
                                expanded={breakfastExpanded}
                                onPress={() => setBreakfastExpanded(!breakfastExpanded)}>
                                <List.Item title="Eggs Benedict" />
                                <List.Item title="Classic Breakfast" />
                            </List.Accordion>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    );
                }}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
            />
        </SafeArea>
    );
};
```

But as you see when a user clicks on the card the user will be navigate to some subcategories. So that works all fine. But I just don't know how to trigger just the detail text, so that the list.accordinon will be shown.

Question: how to trigger the detail text?

Oke, I divided, like:

```
<CategoryList
                data={categoryList}
                renderItem={({ item }) => {
                    return (
                        <>
                            <TouchableOpacity
                                onPress={() => navigation.navigate("groepen", { subcategories: item.id })}>
                                <CategoryInfoCard category={item} expandedCallBack={handlePress} />
                            </TouchableOpacity>

                            <List.Accordion
                                title="Breakfast"
                                left={(props) => <List.Icon {...props} icon="bread-slice" />}
                                expanded={breakfastExpanded}
                                onPress={() => setBreakfastExpanded(!breakfastExpanded)}>
                                <List.Item title="Eggs Benedict" />
                                <List.Item title="Classic Breakfast" />
                            </List.Accordion>
                        </>
                    );
                }}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
            />
```

And so you can click on the accordion without triggering the whole card. But the detail text still triggers the whole card.

If I press on detail. Then this will be also triggered:

```
<TouchableOpacity
                                onPress={() => navigation.navigate("groepen", { subcategories: item.id })}>
                                <CategoryInfoCard category={item} />
                            </TouchableOpacity>
```

What of course not has to be.

Comment: which detail text you need to trigger from CategoryInfoCard  or CategoryScreen. But each every element like Text, Touchable Opacity  have onPress() function can tigger. 
Set true setBreakfastExpanded() to show list.accordinon

I hope you know above all and I can't sure. So describe detail what you need and  Don’t past all code

Comment: @siddhu. Thank you for your reply. But there is only one detail text:  <ButtonDetail>
                    <Detail>{detail}</Detail>
                </ButtonDetail> . So if a user press on the detail text then something has to be happen. And in this case showing the list.accordion.

Comment: The problem I am facing. Is if I do it like: <Text onPress={() => console.log("Text pressed!")}>{detail}</Text> then if I press on the text then the whole card is triggered. So not only the text. That is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

live example https://snack.expo.dev/@saraexpo/-stoppropagation-react-native-

You asking for e.stopPropagation() react native

Prevent parent element /TouchableOpacity/Button   from child/nexted TouchableOpacity or button  OnPress event react native

```
 <TouchableOpacity style={{backgroundColor:'red', width:200, height:200}} onPress={ClickMeParent}   >
      <View onStartShouldSetResponder={(event) => true} onTouchEnd={(e)=>{ e.stopPropagation()}}>
        <Text style={{color:'#000', backgroundColor:'#fff', margin:50, fontSize:20}} onPress={ClickMeChild} > Im Child  </Text>
      </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: @sidhu. Thank you. But what is setExpanded? You have to declare that somewhere isnt? Or you mean setBreakfastExpanded?

Comment: @sidhu.But I think the problem is that everything between TouchableOpacity will be triggerd. So if a user clicks on detail the whole card will be triggered. Not only the text

Comment: So how to tigger only the detail text? And not the whole card

Comment: @siddhu.Did you see my messages?